# Udisks reporting stale NFS handle upon mounting external USB partition?

Tags: usb, mount, nfs, udisks

Using Ubuntu 12.04, kernel 3.2.0; on this machine, I have attached external USB hard disk enclosure. To avoid thinking about mount points, I mount a partition from that hard-disk usually with:

```
sudo udisks --mount /dev/sdc6
```

... which typically works after a reboot.

But just now, upon doing the same, I get this:

```
$ sudo udisks --mount /dev/sdc6
Mount failed: Error mounting: mount: Stale NFS file handle
```

... which is pretty bizarre - given that I haven't had network (NFS) shares mounted on this PC in the last year?

The only thing suspicious I can remember, is I have set this PC to suspend with the USB enclosure on, and then woken it - but why would this have such an influence, so as to be detected as "NFS" error ?!

So my question are: how is it even possible that I get this error; and is there anything I can do (like call some shell commands) to "reset" the mounting state so I can mount the partition successfully - short of rebooting the PC?

---

EDIT: this error persisted after a reboot, which hasn't happened before - so likely I have a hardware error on the partition; still the error is quite weird...

Answer (score 1):

Well, turns out it really was a hardware problem, but got it fixed with `fsck`:

```
$ sudo fsck /dev/sdc6 
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42 (29-Nov-2011)
fsck.ext2: Group descriptors look bad... trying backup blocks...
MYDISK2 was not cleanly unmounted, check forced.
Resize inode not valid.  Recreate<y>? yes

Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Root inode is not a directory.  Clear<y>? yes

Inode 8, i_blocks is 0, should be 262408.  Fix<y>? yes

Inode 10 has a bad extended attribute block 806.  Clear<y>? yes

Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Entry '..' in ??? (130049) has deleted/unused inode 2.  Clear<y>? yes

Entry '..' in ??? (186945) has deleted/unused inode 2.  Clear<y>? yes
...
Directories count wrong for group #24 (0, counted=18).
Fix<y>? yes

Free inodes count wrong (300724, counted=293111).
Fix<y>? yes


MYDISK2: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
MYDISK2: 7625/300736 files (8.7% non-contiguous), 127567/1202859 blocks
```

Then running `fsck` for second time is fine:

```
$ sudo fsck /dev/sdc6 
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42 (29-Nov-2011)
MYDISK2: clean, 7625/300736 files, 127567/1202859 blocks
```

And then I can mount:

```
$ sudo udisks --mount /dev/sdc6
Mounted /org/freedesktop/UDisks/devices/sdc6 at /media/MYDISK2
```